# Masonry is leaving several gaps

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid-layout, masonry

I have checked all the posts concerning this topic, but none of the solutions worked for me.

This is what my grid looks like:

[image]

Here is the [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/Loxfgb74/) and here is the code. HTML:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Masonry -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


<!-- imagesLoaded -->
<script 
src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js">

// init Masonry
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
</script>


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>

  <div class="container">

        <div class="grid">

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="http://hiphopgoldenage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/MellowManAce.jpg" alt="Mellow Man Ace">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C2O6p6ZWgAA67jA.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="http://images1.mtv.com/uri/mgid:file:docroot:mtv.com:/shared/promoimages/bands/c/cypres_hill/photos/cr_rene_cervantes/flipbook/CH-0141.jpg?enlarge=false&matte=true&matteColor=black&quality=0.85" alt="...">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/600/1*VfCrfkNhTVwAxftgfebcog.jpeg" alt="...">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="https://images.genius.com/ace91b03cd16b6f3678660cd184af26a.500x323x1.jpg" alt="...">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271560/pexels-photo-271560.jpeg" alt="...">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/147504/pexels-photo-147504.jpeg" alt="...">
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="...">
          </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* force scrollbar */
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
/* body { font-family: sans-serif; } */

/* ---- grid ---- */
.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
}
.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

What am I doing wring? Please help me.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first problem is that a script tag can't have both a src and inner text. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43240177/227299 has the other details of what you're missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the javascript in it's own `script` tag (without a `src`) and you need to put the jquery you're using with `imagesLoaded()` in `$(document).ready()` (or `$(function(){})`) and no need to specify `columnWidth` with your layout as the column width is in your CSS.

```css
.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
    });
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
      $grid.masonry('layout');
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="http://hiphopgoldenage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/MellowManAce.jpg" alt="Mellow Man Ace">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C2O6p6ZWgAA67jA.jpg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="http://images1.mtv.com/uri/mgid:file:docroot:mtv.com:/shared/promoimages/bands/c/cypres_hill/photos/cr_rene_cervantes/flipbook/CH-0141.jpg?enlarge=false&matte=true&matteColor=black&quality=0.85" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/600/1*VfCrfkNhTVwAxftgfebcog.jpeg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.genius.com/ace91b03cd16b6f3678660cd184af26a.500x323x1.jpg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/271560/pexels-photo-271560.jpeg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/147504/pexels-photo-147504.jpeg" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do is using a real width value, so if you want to get it automatically (because yours are in percentage) just get the grid-item width.

This is a way to do:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: $(".grid-item").width()
});
```

Example running: https://jsfiddle.net/hqLj5t55/